# (index):583 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to load json data into DataTable but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var newdata=[{"id":1,"name":"Mark"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
    $('#user_details').DataTable().rows.add(newdata).draw();

});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="user_details">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a semicolon after {2,"John"}]

Comment: My bad typo mistake.